# Why my Ubuntu 22.04 is taking very long time to run "dpkg --configure -a command"?

Tags: 20.04, dpkg, error-handling, linux-headers, helpfile

sudo dpkg --configure -a
this is the command which i have used to unlock the dpkg file.

following was the lock error:

E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
Is their any way through which i can get rid of using the command and proceed with other installations?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1478302/edit) to show us the complete output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.